# Possible for specific hardware to cause memory leaks?

Tags: stress-testing

I'm running a stress test for about 12 hours on some new hardware we just got. My new baselines look ok but one process is worse than before. Only one process is a culprit. I've tried so many variables to try to figure this out. Short of providing UMDH logs to the developer I can't figure out what's causing the memory leak. (logs are on the way to him)

I've rerun the test on some other hardware and the results look great.

Comment: The answers below are correct, I'd probably try to run a profiling tool to see what specific functions in the code are causing the issue and see if that can help point to the root cause.  It could be hardware specific, but also configuration related, have you verified that the hardware/software installed on the systems are configured the same?  Not sure what kind of app/processes are running, but JVM settings, Tomcat Settings, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the software interacts with.  It's entirely possible for specific hardware to cause the software to go down an atypical path that leaks memory.

Comment: It might even be a typical path, just running in different timing or constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Different platforms could very well have different results. The chipset and drivers could provide differing results.